# How to retrieve IotHub usage information inside Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-functions-isolated

Is there an api or SDK that allows us to retrieve the IoT hub usages information like, the total amount of message sent, daily usages etc. Below is the image of information I am upto.
[image]
The Azure function's function worker runtime is: dotnet-isolated

Comment: there isn't a direct API or SDK within the Azure Functions runtime to access IoT Hub usage metrics.Navigate to the Azure portal and locate your IoT Hub resource.
Go to the "Monitoring" section.
Under "Insights," select "Metrics."
Explore the available metrics, such as "Messages Received" and "Messages Sent." You can filter by time range and granularity (daily, hourly, etc.).

Comment: Another way is to create  a Create an Alert from App Insights to Send an Email [Notification](https://mattruma.com/adventures-with-azure-functions-create-an-alert-from-app-insight-to-send-an-email-notification/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/monitor-iot-hub), we can monitor Azure IoT Hub by collecting and analyzing various types of logs, including platform metrics, resource logs, connections, device telemetry, C2D commands, activity logs, etc.

- Go to Azure IoT Hub and set up diagnostic settings in your IoT Hub to collect and route platform metrics, resource logs, and activity logs to Azure Monitor Logs, Azure Storage, or an Event Hubs endpoint.
- Configure diagnostic settings to specify which categories of logs to collect based on your monitoring requirements.

[image]

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

namespace FunctionApp
{
    public static class TimerFunction
    {
        private static EventHubClient? eventHubClient; // Nullable eventHubClient
        private static readonly string connectionString = "EventHubconnectionString";
        private static readonly string eventHubName = "eventHubName";

        [Function("TimerFunction")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("TimerFunction");

            logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            // Build the connection string with Event Hub name
            var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
            {
                EntityPath = eventHubName
            };
            string eventHubConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();

            // Create Event Hub client
            eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(eventHubConnectionString);

            var runtimeInformation = await eventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformationAsync();
            var d2cPartitions = runtimeInformation.PartitionIds;
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (string partition in d2cPartitions)
            {
                tasks.Add(ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(partition, cts.Token, logger));
            }

            await Task.Delay(60000); // Ensure the function runs for 1 minute

            logger.LogInformation("Exiting...");
            cts.Cancel();
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        private static async Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(string partition, CancellationToken ct, ILogger logger)
        {
            var eventHubReceiver = eventHubClient!.CreateReceiver("$Default", partition, EventPosition.FromEnqueuedTime(DateTime.Now));
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    var eventDataBatch = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync(100); // Maximum number of events to receive
                    if (eventDataBatch != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var eventData in eventDataBatch)
                        {
                            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array);
                            logger.LogInformation($"Message received. Partition: {partition} Data: '{data}'");
                            var message = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureMonitorDiagnosticLog>(data);
                            // Process the message...
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError($"Error receiving message from partition {partition}: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            await eventHubReceiver.CloseAsync();
        }
    }

    class AzureMonitorDiagnosticLog
    {
        public string? time { get; set; }
        public string? resourceId { get; set; }
        public string? operationName { get; set; }
        public string? category { get; set; }
        public string? level { get; set; }
        public string? resultType { get; set; }
        public string? resultDescription { get; set; }
        public string? durationMs { get; set; }
        public string? callerIpAddress { get; set; }
        public string? correlationId { get; set; }
        public string? identity { get; set; }
        public string? location { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string>? properties { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Another way is to use [alert](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/iot-hub-new-alerts/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20started%3A%201%20Go%20to%20your%20IoT,Follow%20prompts%20to%20finish%20setting%20up%20the%20alert.) rules in Azure [IoT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-manage-alert-rules) Hub.
[image]